# How to access App::Persistence in REPL console in RubyMotion

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, rubymotion

I've saved variables like AuthToken into the App::Persistence store, but I want to debug it. Can I access this through the REPL console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.  `App::Persistence["AuthToken"]` will work just fine in the REPL.

If you want to get all the contents of the persistent store, try `App::Persistence.storage.dictionaryRepresentation`.  Look for the keys that begin with your app identifier (`com.yourcompany.Appname_`).